# Issue with uploading file with SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, file-upload, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to upload file to SharePoint 2013 on-premise through REST API. Below is my main function

In below function it always throw error, I tried with getScript but it never goes inside the getScript then I added SP.RequestExecutor.js into my header but it throw error. Very few time it get succeeded and uploaded. Please help me on this.

```
function uploadFileHolder(listName, id, file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var fileName = file.name;
    getFileBuffer(file).then(
            function (buffer) {
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                var binary = '';
                for (var b = 0; b < bytes.length; b++) {
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[b]);
                }
                console.log(' File size:' + bytes.length);
                //$.getScript("http://darwaza.kuwaitairways.com/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
                var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
                createitem.executeAsync({
                    url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                    method: "POST",
                    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                    body: binary,
                    success: fsucc,
                    error: ferr,
                    state: "Update"
                });
                function fsucc(data) {
                    console.log(data + ' uploaded successfully');
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }
                function ferr(data, args, errorMessage) {
                    console.log('error\n\n' + data.statusText + "\n\n" + data.responseText);
                    deferred.reject(data);
                }
                //});
            },
            function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$.getscript is asynchronous call so it won't register immediately inside the page. So you have to make the $.getscript call synchronous. Like below,

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
 $.getScript('<your_script_url>');
 $.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

else, you can run your code once the $.getscript execution is completed.Like below,

```
$.getScript(script_url).done(function(){
        //  Unrelated stuff here
        // do something with $element after the script loaded.
});
```